# How to create vertical parabolic path in XNA 2D game?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing a XNA based 2D-game for Windows Phone 7.1. My requirement is to flick an object, based on the amount and angle of flick, it will animate in a vertical projectile motion. For e.g. there is a lake infront of you, and you want to throw a stone into it. The same motion has to be replicated with camera being human's eye.

There are 3 levels of distance to be covered. The distance covered in Y-axis is more than the distance covered in X-axis.

I could see many equations given for projectile motion in horizontal (X-) axis but none to show projectile motion in Y-axis.

Any idea how to achieve this projectile motion in terms of X- and Y- coordinates?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers to your questions. You should mark answers as correct by clicking the tick to the left of a post.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `Vector2` instead of an angle, you can implement a very rudimentary physics engine which will be simple and accurate.

The object to be flicked will have a `Vector2 Velocity` and a `Vector2 Position`.

Then you can just add the distance between the mouse as a `Vector2` to the `Velocity`, and add the `Velocity` to the `Position` every frame, and then add gravity.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
public class FlickObject
{
    public Vector2 Velocity;
    public Vector2 Position;

    public FlickObject () {}

    public void Update(GameTime t)
    {
        Position += Velocity;
    }
}
```

And in the game class (when the user flicks the object):

```
flickObject.Velocity += FlickDistance;
```

Where `FlickDistance` is the distance between the mouse (or however you calculate it) and the object.

To finish it off, add gravity:

```
flickObject.Velocity += new Vector2(0, GRAVITY);
```

Where `GRAVITY` is set to some positive value.